# Is every strong homomorphism of structures surjective?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm reading Rautenberg's *A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic* and he writes

> **Homomorphism theorem**. Let *A* be *L*-structure and $\approx$ a congruence
> in *A*. Then $k: a 
> \mapsto a/\approx$ is a strong homomorphism from *A* onto $A/\approx$,
> the canonical homomorphism. Conversely, if $h: A \to B$ is a strong homomorphism from *A* onto an *L*-structure *B* with kernel ≈ then $\iota : a/≈ 
> \mapsto ha$
> is an isomorphism from *A/≈* to *B*, and *h = ı ◦ k*.

> **Proof**. We omit here the superscripts for *f* and *r* just for the sake of
> legibility. Clearly, $kf\vec a = (f\vec a)/≈ = f(\vec a/≈) = fk\vec a =f(ka_1, \dots , ka_n)$
> and $(\exists \vec b\in A^n)(k\vec a = k\vec b \& r\vec b)⇔ (∃\vec b≈\vec a)r\vec b ⇔ r\vec a/≈ ⇔ r k\vec a $ by definition.
> Hence *k* is what we claimed. The definition of $\iota$ is sound, and $\iota$ is bijective
> since *ha = hb ⇒ a/≈ = b/≈*. ...

The part I'm not clear on is how we know that $\iota$ is surjective.  If we let $b\in B$, then I can't see any guarantee that there is some element $a\in A$ such that $h(a)=b$ nor that $\iota(a/\approx) = b$.  I thought perhaps it would be due to the kernel of $h$ being $\approx$.  However, that too seems to require an additional assumption of surjectivity to work (as far as I can tell).  Here are the definitions relevant to congruence relations given in the text:

> **Congruences**. A congruence relation (or simply a congruence) in a structure $\mathcal A$ of signature *L* is an equivalence relation ≈ in *A* such that for all
> *n > 0*, all *f ∈ L* of arity *n*, and all $\vec a,\vec b ∈ A^n,$
> $$\vec a ≈ \vec b ⇒ fA\vec a ≈ fA\vec b$$
> Here $\vec a ≈ \vec b$ means $a_i ≈ b_i$ for $i = 1, \dots , n$. [...] If *h: A → B* is a homomorphism then $≈_h ⊆ A^2$, defined
> by $ a ≈_h b ⇔ ha = hb$, is a congruence in *A*, called the kernel of *h*. Let
> $A'$ be the set of equivalence classes *a/≈ := {x ∈ A | a ≈ x}* for *a ∈ A*,
> also called the congruence classes of ≈, and set $\vec a/≈ := (a_1/≈, ... , a_n/≈)$
> for $\vec a ∈ A_n$. Define $f^{A'}(\vec a/≈) := (f^{A}a)/≈$ and let $r^{ A'}a/≈ ⇔ (∃\vec b≈\vec a)r^{A}\vec b$.

Comment: Note that $h$ is explicitly assumed to be surjective: "if $h:A\rightarrow B$ is a strong homomorphism from $A$ **onto** an $L$-structure $B$" (emph. mine). Remember that "onto" is a synonym for "surjective."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, that makes sense now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that surjectivity of $h$ is needed, but it's not missing from the text!

This is a terminology issue: the term "onto" **does** imply surjectivity. Specifically, "a homomorphism of $A$ onto $B$" means "a homomorphism from $A$ to $B$ which is surjective." In particular, the assumption that $h$ is surjective is present when Rautenberg writes

> if $h:A\rightarrow B$ is a strong homomorphism from $A$ **onto** an $L$-structure $B$

(emphasis mine).